# Keep additional rows when DBConcurrencyException is raised

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, concurrency

I made a simple application that displays data from a database in a DataGridView, users can add rows, delete rows, update values and save the changes.

Now, let's say User A modifies a value in row 8 and saves. User B adds 50 rows and wants to modify a cell in row 8 also. When user B saves, DBConcurrencyException occurs and all his work is lost.
Considering the way people will use this app, this scenario should not happen but there is still a small chance.

Is it possible to keep the added rows when the DBConcurrencyException is raised ? Or should I just tell the users to save as often as possible ?

Here is the relevant code :

```
private BindingSource bindingSource = null;
private SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = null;

string conStringLocal = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

SqlCommand command;
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter;

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataBind();
}

private void DataBind()
{
    dataGridViewCND.DataSource = null;
    dataTable.Clear();
    string query = "SELECT * FROM myTable";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStringLocal);

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        command = con.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = query;
        dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        bindingSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = dataTable };
        dataGridViewCND.DataSource = bindingSource;
        this.dataGridViewCND.Columns["id"].Visible = false;
        this.dataGridViewCND.Sort(this.dataGridViewCND.Columns["Date"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      // GENERIC ERROR MESSAGE 
    }
}

private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        dataGridViewCND.EndEdit();
        dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
        DataBind();
        // UPDATE SUCCESS MESSAGE
    }
    catch(DBConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        // CONCURRENCY ERROR MESSAGE
        DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // GENERIC ERROR MESSAGE
        DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does your application allow a user to add new rows and edit existing rows without saving anything? Data manipulation should be done in small pieces. Storing up a bunch of changes to the database is not a very good idea.

Comment: @SeanLange So, the best way would be to update everytime a user stops editing a cell and the data validation is OK ?

Comment: Yes. That is the same thing a person does. You edit a row which is a single unit of work. Then you start editing another row. You might even take a break in between. If you keep your data in a state of flux like that you are just asking for trouble.

Comment: @SeanLange Sounds good to me. Now I'm just afraid the users will get lost if they can't find a "Save" button as this program is supposed to replace and automate an old Excel sheet. They're not tech savvy people.

Comment: You might be surprised. Even non technical people can pretty quickly get used to not being forced to click a button to save when it does it automagically. :) You could even add a message at the bottom of the window in the status bar perhaps that it was saved.